# Как в дочерней форме правильно найти координаты курсора в относительно самой дочерней формы для приближения картинки Winforms MDI C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, изображения

Пишу приложение для открытия картинок через **MDI WinForms**. И в приложении мне нужно сделать приближение картинки через инструмент "лупа".

Для отображение картинки в этом приложении я использую объект `Graphics`.

Отображение картинки идет со смещением, потому что отсчет объекта `Cursor` идет относительно родительской формы(как я понял), а мне нужно, чтобы было относительно дочерней. То есть, **ошибка идет при вычислении места, относительно которого затем выполняется приближение(перерисовка) картинки.**

Я пытался что-то придумать, и всё, что у меня вышло - приведено в коде ниже. Так же прилаживаю пару скринов этого бага.

Пример кода ниже:
`graphics` - поле, что содержит графику;
`ImageBuffer` - поле, в которой лежит картинка(`Bitmap`), что отображается в дочернем окне;
`coefficient` - коэффициент, на который увеличивается картинка;
`parent` - родительская форма

```
 graphics.DrawImage(ImageBuffer, 
                    -Cursor.Position.X + ImageBuffer.Width + parent.PointToScreen(Location).X,
                    -Cursor.Position.Y + ImageBuffer.Height + parent.PointToScreen(Location).Y,
                    ImageBuffer.Width * coefficient,
                    ImageBuffer.Height * coefficient);
```

Нажимаем на точечку, к которой ведет стрелочка:

[image: Картинка1]

Получаем такую картинку:

[image: Картинка 2]

Хотя, мы должны были приблизиться к той точке, на груди. Она должна была быть в центре. Заранее благодарю, за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так я изменил свою формулу отображения:

```
Point cursor = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

graphics.DrawImage(
   ImageBuffer, 
   -cursor.X,
   -cursor.Y,
   ClientRectangle.Width * coefficient,
   ClientRectangle.Height * coefficient);
```

И картинка корректно растянулась и начала отображаться на форме. Приближаться так же начала корректно.

Comment: `FormName_MouseMove` делает еучу лишней работы если юзер ничего не нажимает. Получайте координаты тогда, когда они действительно нужны. `Point cursor = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);`

Comment: @aepot Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если помогло, можете обновить ответ, вдруг кому-то пригодится в будущем.

Comment: А, хорошо, спасибо!